# Cannot display JPEG image in PHP Laravel project

Tags: php, html, file, directory, laravel-8

Does anybody know what can call these files properly?

I'm trying to put text on a JPEG image, and apparently the way I'm calling those 2 files is not working

It is a PHP 7.4 Laravel 8 project and the script is located in a blade view.

```html
<?php


// C:\xampp\htdocs\solidcadclass\public\storage\resources\arial.ttf
// C:\xampp\htdocs\solidcadclass\public\storage\resources\template.jpeg

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('C:\xampp\htdocs\solidcadclass\public\storage\resources\template.jpeg');

$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0); // OBJ, RGB
$txt = Auth::user()->name;
$font = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\solidcadclass\public\storage\resources\arial.ttf';

imagettftext(
    $img,           // Image object
    24,             // Font Size
    0,              // Angle
    5, 24,          // x,y
    $black,         // Color
    $font,          // Font to use
    $txt            // Text to write
);

// OUTPUT IMAGE
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
```

I am getting bunch of weird symbols like:

```
����JFIF ...
```

Any advice on how to call files in functions like these would be really useful!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel response function with passing image in response parameter.

```
return response($img)->header('Content-type','image/jpeg');
```

Comment: Ive tried yours and many other solutions but nothing seems to work :/ I will try to do it with another language or maybe just kill myself